# How to document module.exports defined with object.defineProperty

Tags: node.js, documentation, jsdoc

I'm using NodeJS and trying to get the JSDoc to property pick up what I'm doing. I have some code that looks like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(module, 'exports', {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    get: function() {
        const factory = {};

        /**
         * Output message to the console
         * @param {string} str
         */
        factory.foo = function(str) {
            console.log(str);
        };

        return factory;
    }
});
```

**Exporting foo the standard way `exports.foo = function(str) { ... }` is not an option in this case.**

Another module can include this module has access to foo (just as if it were exported directly). For example:

```
var x = require('./x');
x.foo('Hello');
```

So how can I document this so that jsDoc picks up that this module has a function foo?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that seems to work:

```
Object.defineProperty(module, 'exports', {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    get: Factory
});

/**
 * Get a factory object.
 * @returns {Factory}
 * @constructor
 */
function Factory() {
    var factory = Object.create(Factory.prototype);

    /**
     * Output a message to the console.
     * @name Factory#foo
     * @param {string} str
     */
    factory.foo = function(str) {
        console.log(str);
    };

    return factory;
}
```